# SQL: product with multiple categories

Tags: mysql, database-design

Wich is the best database design and performance to store multiple categories (at least 3) per product? Products table could have milions of items.

To have two tables **products** and **products_relationship** (where to store product_id and category_id)?

And what about selecting products that have assigned both category 1 and 2?

1. SELECT IN() will select 1 or 2
2. 2 INNER JOIN per products_relationship doesn`t sound greate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design looks good. When you have a *m to n relation* then you should always use such a mapping table.

You can select products that have both categories like this

```
select p.id, p.name
from products p
inner join product_relationship pr on p.id = pr.product_id
inner join categories c on c.id = pr.category_id
where c.name in ('cat1','cat2')
group by p.id, p.name
having count(distinct c.id) = 2
```

And you could name your mapping table different: `product_categories` to indicate what relation you build.

Answer (score 0):

You can create many to many relationship. Google **HABTM** for more

**Product**

```
id name
```

**category**

```
id name
```

**product_category**

```
product_id category_id
```